# hypernator.js: How to only hyphenate words that overflow container?

Tags: javascript, css, hyphenation, hyphenator

I'm wondering if there is way, using [hyphenator.js](https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenator), to only hyphenate words that are larger than the container, but leave all other words the way they are. All other words should just break to the next line (if they can fit the container.)

```js
Hyphenator.config({
  defaultlanguage: 'en'
});
Hyphenator.run();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 50px;
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
}

div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 270px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Hyphenator/5.3.0/Hyphenator.min.js"></script>
<div class="hyphenate">
  <p><strong>with hyphenator</strong>:</p>
  <p>How can I force hyphens on words that are very long, like this one: "Verylongwordthatshouldbehypenated"?</p>
  <p>But, as long as words will fit the container I don't want Hypenation. So there should be no hyphens here: "Iamalongword Cellardoor Anotherlongword Thisisaprettylongword"</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p><strong>What I would like</strong>:</p>
  <p>How can I force hyphens on words that are very long, like this one: "Verylongwordthat&shy;shouldbehypenated"?</p>
  <p>But, as long as words will fit the container I don't want Hypenation. So there should be no hyphens here: "Iamalongword Cellardoor Anotherlongword Thisisaprettylongword"</p>
</div>
```

Using Hyphenator I can break all words like this: `Hyphenator.run();`

The problem is that it will hyphenate words that shouldn't be hyphenated.

Here is a pen to illustrate the problem:
https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/NwxKrr

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at [the documentation](https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenator/blob/wiki/en_PublicAPI.md) and fiddling with your codepen, you can achieve that either by increasing the `leftmin` or `minwordlength` configuration option or enabling `useCSS3hyphenation`.

Comment: Good find. If I could set `'leftmin' : $(container).width()` for each container, that would fix the problem. But not sure if there is an efficient way to do this. EDIT: Oh no, on second thought that won't work, because leftmin is expressed as a number of characters rather than pixels :(